# JS build tool without node

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, angularjs, gruntjs

I am a fan of grunt. But unfortunately, we do not have node and hence the ability to access npm packages in our work environment. I have been creating a HTML5 application using AngularJS+Bootstrap etc. I have been able to start and develop the app using angular seed.


**However, my main problem is the build (obfuscation and minification) process for such a project**. Since ours is a protected environment, I cannot leverage help of other tools like coffeescript etc. I need some tool which may be as good as grunt, but would be available for download directly.


Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: node.js is available for download directly. How come it's OK to install some-random-build-tool but not node.js? It doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Agreed, node is available for direct download. But it needs to be installed and needs admin rights on the machine. Like I said it is a protected environment.

Comment: Then unprotect it. How can anybody expect you to get any work done at this rate? It's like telling your home renovator "ok, we need this room drywalled, but you're not allowed to use your knife or any screws".

Comment: You don't need admin rights to install node. You can install it locally, for your user only.

Comment: @NitzanShaked You are missing the point. Local installation is not my worry. It is about the dev and production environments. Usually developers do not give out the final build from their local machine, rather it is compiled differently on a build server etc.

Comment: I am not sure I even understand the point. What is allowed, and what isn't? In your second-from-the-top comment you say "... node is available for download, ... but needs admin rights". I said it didn't. *If* you are indeed free to download stuff into the {whatever/production/build} servers, download node.js, install locally, download grunt, and be happy and productive.

Comment: Yes, download is allowed but only on my local system. Since we are a huge firm the other servers {prod/build} are only controlled by admins and have a strict no download policy. Hence I need some JS build & packaging tool which comes as a static lib or as a source itself. This will help to keep the tool independent of the host machine and can be maintained along with my source in svn. So now, the admin can checkout this code on a dev box and run the right command/file to create a release build. I hope, I haven't added to the confusion :)

Comment: It sounds like you just need to talk to your ops guys.

Comment: How do you deploy to those environments (dev/prod)? Perhaps what you need is not a new build tool, but a deployment tool/server. That machine can run your Grunt tasks and create a build which is then deployed using rsync/sftp/ssh/whatevs in the fashion you are used to.

Comment: @jakerella Like I said, the office policy prohibits node and hence Grunt. Ergo, my requirement for a tool or a lib which can be part of my source or use jvm. Meanwhile I have been looking at [wro4j](http://code.google.com/p/wro4j/).

Comment: ooooh, I thought you just couldn't get node/grunt on your dev/prod environments - but you aren't allowed to install locally either, even if you could? That sucks. :/ Good luck! (I don't have good suggestions)